# Does the Height property of a UserForm include the Frame?

Tags: vba, excel

I noticed that when I create a UserForm (Height = 180) and a Button (Top = 0) and Increase the Value of the Top property like this:

```
CommandButton1.Top = CommandButton1.Top + UserForm1.Height
```

The CommandButton isn't where I expected it to be.

So is h1 or h2 the actual height of the UserForm?

[image: Picture 1]

Thanks :)

Comment: set `UserForm`'s height to zero. See what happens. That will give you proper understanding.

Comment: That's kinda the problem, it automaticly sets the height to a minimun of 28.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `.InsideHeight` instead of `.Height`, this will give you the internal height of the Userform, without the border and title bar height.

In either case, your code would put the the button outside of the users view.